# Using selenium to login to a canvas webpage

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This script successfully opens chrome and navigates to the desired URL and navigates the landing page by clicking 'Login'. The desired behaviour is that on the second page the given values for username and password are entered and 'login' is clicked. But it just remains on this page without entering user name and password and no other action.

```
import time
from getpass import getpass
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Constants
CANVAS_URL = "https://onlinestudy.york.ac.uk"
USERNAME = "<myUsername>"

PASSWORD = "<myPassword"

# Set up Chrome driver
driver_service = Service("<pathToChromedriver>")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)

# Open Canvas login page
driver.get(f"{CANVAS_URL}")

driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button").click()

# Wait for the login form to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pseudonym_session_unique_id")))

driver.find_element(By.ID, "pseudonym_session_unique_id").send_keys(USERNAME)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "pseudonym_session_password").send_keys(PASSWORD)

# Click the login button on the second page
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "button"))).click()
```

[image: Canvas login screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** There is no attribute `ID=pseudonym_session_unique_id`. Refer the HTML of Username and Password fields below, you will see `ID=username` and `ID=password` respectively for Username and Password elements.

[image]

Change below lines:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pseudonym_session_unique_id")))

driver.find_element(By.ID, "pseudonym_session_unique_id").send_keys(USERNAME)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "pseudonym_session_password").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

**TO:**

```
# Wait for the username and password fields to be clickable and enter username and password
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys(USERNAME)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
```